# Spring 3 \ Quartz 2. Integration problems

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have problems with integration spring and quartz. I need to dynamically added `CronTriggerFactoryBean` to `SchedulerFactoryBean`.

**XML Spring mapping:**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="plannedVacationServiceJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="plannedVacationServiceJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.my.service.package.PlannerJob" />
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="plannedVacationServiceJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="*/15 * * * * ?" />
</bean>
```

**Java code:**

```java
@Service
public class Planner implements Planning { 
@Autowired
@Qualifier("plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger")
private CronTriggerFactoryBean plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger;

@Autowired
private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
       schedulerFactoryBean.start();
 } 
//some code 
private void addTask(PlannerEntity entity) {
    try {
        String name = getIdentityName(entity);
        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(name);
        String cronExpression = getCronExpression(entity);
        plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
        JobDetail jobDetail =      JobBuilder.newJob(PlannerJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey).build();
        plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger.setName(name);
        plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger.afterPropertiesSet();
        schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger.getObject());
        triggers.put(entity.getId(), trigger);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

In this case we have only one trigger, which added in xml mapping

I trying remove reference to triggers from xml and creating CronTriggerFactoryBean from code:

```java
private void addTask(PlannerEntity entity) {
    try {
        String name = getIdentityName(entity);
        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(name);
        String cronExpression = getCronExpression(entity);
        CronTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        trigger.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(PlannerJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey).build();
        trigger.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        trigger.setName(name);
        trigger.afterPropertiesSet();
        schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger.getObject());
        triggers.put(entity.getId(), trigger);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But in this case we dont have any triggers:

```
2014-04-02 14:28:55,144 DEBUG [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread(org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_QuartzSchedulerThread)] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2014-04-02 14:29:18,981 DEBUG [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread(org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_QuartzSchedulerThread)] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2014-04-02 14:29:46,361 DEBUG [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread(org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_QuartzSchedulerThread)] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2014-04-02 14:30:09,439 DEBUG [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread(org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_QuartzSchedulerThread)] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do it that way. `FactoryBean` has a specific contract and you're trying to act in the middle of it.

A [factory bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) is a bean whose purpose is to create a bean programmatically. You can't really inject a factory bean because the sole purpose of its existence is to register a bean. Besides, the `start` callback is related to the application context lifecycle. When you call it from your code, it is too late, the scheduler is already active.

The triggers are registered when the bean is initialized (in the `afterPropertiesSet` callback method). If you try to add additional triggers to the factory after that, it will not be taken into account as the scheduler has already been created.

That being said, I don't really see the relationship between the XML and the Java code. In a regular scenario, your `plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger` should be registered (and there is no reason to make that a `prototype` bean).

Comment: I would advise you to read [the documentation regarding FactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean). If you need to register triggers programmatically, there's nothing wrong by creating a bean that represents that trigger and set it in the factory like you did. Another option is to inherit from the `SchedulerFactoryBean` and override the `afterPropertiesSet` callback to do whatever you want *before* the triggers are registered (so register stuff and **then** call `super.afterPropertiesSet()`)

Comment: Thanks all, guys. Also, problem was fixed. I'm using `CronIriggerImpl` (from quartz) class instead of `CronTriggerFactoryBean` (from spring) and removing mapping for triggers from XML